# Image name not inserted to Mysql Database after image resize and upload

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I have written some codes to collect images, re-size, upload to two different folders and store the new name in a mysql database. Every other aspect of the code is working. The only issue i am having is that, the new name given to the image is not being stored in the datatbase. What i am getting is just a single digit. E.g rather than have the name of file uploaded as 1234_12345.jpg stored in the database, the file name stored is just say 1 or 3 etc.

Below is my form:

```
<form method="POST" id="adimageadd" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" name="adimageadd" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="h1">Select Album:</div>
                    <select class="input-field-login2" id="albumselect" name="albumselect" required type="text" tabindex="1">
                        <option value="">Please Select</option>
                        <?php foreach ($result_album as $rs) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $rs["alID"]; ?>"><?php echo $rs["alTitle"]; ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="" />
                    <input name="photo[]" type="file" required id="photo" size="26" multiple='multiple'/>
                    <button name="login" type="submit" id="login_submit" tabindex="3">Add Images</button>
                    <input type="hidden" name="form_insert" value="adimageadd">
                </form>
```

And the php code is:

```
function getExtension($str) {

         $i = strrpos($str,".");
         if (!$i) { return ""; } 

         $l = strlen($str) - $i;
         $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
         return $ext;
 }

 define ("MAX_SIZE","2048");
    $errors=0;

    $query_album = "SELECT alID, alTitle, alImage, alDesc FROM galbum ORDER BY alID DESC";
    $result_album = mysqli_query($connKcla, $query_album);
    $row_album = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_album);
    $totalRows_album = mysqli_num_rows($result_album); 

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

    if ((isset($_POST["form_insert"])) && ($_POST["form_insert"] == "adimageadd")) {

    //get form details and check for sql injections and disable them
    $albumRef = mysqli_real_escape_string($connKcla, $_POST['albumselect']);
    $image = $_FILES["photo"]["name"];
    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']; 

    $img = count($image);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $img; $i++) { 

    if ($image){

    $filename = mysqli_real_escape_string($connKcla, $image[$i]);
    $extension = getExtension($filename);
    $extension = strtolower($extension);

    if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")) 
    {
        echo ' Unknown Image extension ';
        $errors=1;
    }
    else
    {
        $size=filesize($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'][$i]);

    if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)
    {
        echo "Your image has exceeded the size limit of 2Mb. Click the back button on your browser to re-enter the right size of image";
        $errors=1;
    }

    if($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="jpeg" )
    {
    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);
    }
    else if($extension=="png")
    {
    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);
    }
    else 
    {
    $src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);
    }

    list($width,$height)=getimagesize($uploadedfile);

    $newwidth=760;
    $newheight=($height/$width)*$newwidth;
    $tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);

    imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);

    $thumbnewwidth=250;
    $thumbnewheight=($height/$width)*$thumbnewwidth;
    $thumbtmp=imagecreatetruecolor($thumbnewwidth,$thumbnewheight);

    imagecopyresampled($thumbtmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$thumbnewwidth,$thumbnewheight,$width,$height);

    $set['photo'] = $image[$i];
    $kaboom = explode(".", $image[$i]);
    $pixExt = end($kaboom);
    $photo = rand()."_".time().".".$pixExt;

    $target = "../gallery/images/". $photo;
    $thumbtarget = "../gallery/images/thumbs/". $photo;

    imagejpeg($tmp,$target,100);
    imagejpeg($thumbtmp,$thumbtarget,75);

    imagedestroy($src);
    imagedestroy($tmp);
    imagedestroy($thumbtmp);
    }
    }


        $stmt = $connKcla->prepare("INSERT INTO gimage (imImage, albumRef) VALUES ($photo[$i], $albumRef)");
        $results = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();


        if($results){
        $updateGoTo = "confirm.php"; 
        if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
        $updateGoTo .= (strpos($updateGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
        $updateGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
        }
        header("Location: ". $updateGoTo);
        }else{
        header("Location: error.php");
        }
    }
    }
```

Please any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I just changed the value part of the query from:

```
$stmt = $connKcla->prepare("INSERT INTO gimage (imImage, albumRef) VALUES ($photo[$i], $albumRef)");
```

to

```
$stmt = $connKcla->prepare("INSERT INTO gimage (imImage, albumRef) VALUES ('$photo', '$albumRef')");
```

Answer (score 1):

This creates a string:

```
$photo = rand()."_".time().".".$pixExt;
```

This gets one character from that string:

```
$photo[$i]
```

Which you're storing in your database:

```
$stmt = $connKcla->prepare("INSERT INTO gimage (imImage, albumRef) VALUES ($photo[$i], $albumRef)");
```

If you want to store the whole string, just use the string itself and not the index of a specific character:

```
$stmt = $connKcla->prepare("INSERT INTO gimage (imImage, albumRef) VALUES ($photo, $albumRef)");
                                                                            //^-- here
```

---

Additionally, you should probably start looking into using query parameters and prepared statements.  While this code may *coincidentally* not currently be open to SQL injection if none of the input is from users, it's still difficult to *guarantee* that.  And not being open to SQL injection is a good habit to get into in general.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did that initially, but i kept getting an error: "Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in ......"

Comment: @AgbogidiMichael: That means your SQL query was failing.  A cursory search on that exact error message will find many questions and answers about it.

Comment: Thnaks. But its a simple insert into database statement. The $albumRef field is being inserted into the database. Its just the $photo field that is the issue.

Comment: @AgbogidiMichael: Which is exactly what this answer corrects.  In your previous comment you mentioned a separate issue, for which you'd need to determine the actual reason why the query is failing.  Check for errors after preparing the query.

Comment: Thanks @David for your valuable help. I have been able to solve the problem. Everything works fine now.